# Knockout Custom Binding - Works in jsfiddle, but not in Durandal

Tags: knockout.js, durandal, durandal-2.0

Absolutely love Durandal's architecture/clarity. But have ran into trouble getting `durandal 2.0.1` to recognize *any* custom knockout binding.

My example View contains:

```
<div data-bind="test: {}" />
```

The binding is defined within an `appBindings.js` that contains:

```
define([ 'jquery', 'knockout'], 
  function ($, ko) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.test = {
      init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {alert(0);},
      update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {alert(1);}
    }
    var model = function(){} 
    return new model();
});
```

That is `required` from `main`:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        ...
        'durandal':'../lib/durandal/js',
        'jquery': '../lib/jquery/jquery-1.9.1',
        'knockout': '../lib/knockout/js/knockout-3.1.0',
        'bootstrap': '../lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap',
        ...
        'bindings': 'bindings/appBindings'
    },
    shim: {
        'bootstrap': ['jquery'],
        //'ko-binding-test': ['jquery','knockout'],


    }
});

define(['libs/core','durandal/system', 'durandal/app',
            'durandal/viewLocator','services/resourceService','bindings'],  
    function (core, system, app, viewLocator, resourceService, bindings) {
    //...
});
```

Observations:

- Chrome's traffic shows `appBindings.js` being loaded.
- can breakpoint within `appBindings.js` as it gets loaded.
- **but no matter what I try, `init`/`update` are never invoked.**
- the binding is functional outside of durandal  (http://jsfiddle.net/skysigal/8LJw5/3/)

I've also tried various other ways of loading the binding definition:

- using in `main` a `define` + `shim` of a non-AMD file containing the binding definition.
- loading a non-AMD file (containing the binding definition) directly from index.html using a script tag
- making it a dependency of the `view`, not `main`.

Anyone have a suggestion as to the proper way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: So `appBindings.js` is loaded, but can you confirm it is loaded **after ko** and **before running `ko.applyBindings`**?

Comment: Bonsoir! Yes. appBidings.js was loaded, after ko, and before ko.applyBindings. ... 
The issue turned out to be caused by a binding on the page that failed earlier. I just didn't look for that, thinking it just had to be the custom binding...

Comment: Happens! Nice French skills :)